# How can I see POST with iDrac6?

Tags: drac

I have used iDRAC in the past on Dell servers, and I thought I could see POST, and the whole boot process.  I cannot on a server I am working on.  I can see the OS when it boots when I use the Viewer, but I cannot watch the entire boot process.  When I reboot from the OS the viewer dies like if I was using VNC.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:  It is the Enterprise version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply shouldn't happen. If you connect to the iDRAC controller and start a remote view session you should stay connected. The only reason this should stop is if the power from the server is removed. A normal power cycle should not affect the viewer.

Please check if you have the latest firmware on the controller.